Is there a suffix order for verb conjugation?
Recently learnt about the 12 suffix forms in Japanese (technically 13 but Wikipedia considers Desiderative mood its own thing) and was curious if there was a specific order to the suffixes and if not does the order affect the meaning?

What do you mean by suffix?  There are inflected forms for verb. 　書きたい (I want to write)　書かれた (It was written).  There are other situations in which certain verbs can be concatenated 書き終わる (I finish writing).  There are other expressions like 書くところ (I'm about to write)... Without any further clarification, it's hard for us to give you an answer.  Perhaps give examples of these so-called suffixes you found.

@A.Ellett My guess is that they're wondering about things like https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/86605/causative-passive-form-vs-passive-causative-form-both-are-grammatically-possib

There is I think no consensus on how to count "suffix forms" that you (presumably) mention. As the previous comment says, you need to explicitly list what you are talking about in order for us to understand your question.

Based on their mention of Wikipedia, I think it's pretty clear they're referring to the 12 verb forms as presented in the Japanese conjugation article (Imperfective, Negative, Perfective, te form, Conjunctive, Volitional, Passive, Causative, Imperative, Potential, Conditional).

I think more productive than trying to figure out an "overall" order of priority here (which is an extremely zoomed out point of view), is to think in terms of "suffix compatibility" or "stackable inflections" (and learning about them on a per-form basis; taking the decision tree branch-by-branch). As such, I won't be providing a full answer here, but rather demonstrating the logic of how this works.
You start with the dictionary form of the verb (e.g. 書く). This form could be conjugated to a number of possible inflections, some of which are dead ends, and some allowing you to further inflect from there.
For instance, inflecting to the past (書く → 書いた) or volitional (書く → 書こう) terminates the chain. Inflecting to the passive (書かれる) or the potential (書ける) essentially results in a new dictionary form, and you can go on to apply a second layer of inflection from there (e.g. you could get 書かれた or 書けた for their past, in which case you'd again be left with no way to continue). In this way, you could create a chain of 4, 5, even 6 layers of inflection:

書く → 書かせる +causative → 書かせられる +passive → 書かせられたい +desirative　→ 書かせられたくない +negative → 書かせられたくなければ +conditional

"write" → "make sb write" → "be made to write" → "want to be made to write" → "don't want to be made to write" → "if (you) don't want to be made to write..."


The causative (書かせる) is another example of a form that, in and of itself, behaves like a base verb (note the "-u" ending), so you can stack the passive on top of it, which once again results in a dictionary-form-type verb. Adding -たい to that then gives you a word that behaves like an い-adjective, meaning you can go on to make it negative (by doing -い → -く+ない). This gives you yet another い-adjective-like word (again, note the ending), to which you can apply the -ば conditional (-い → -ければ), and thus we finally arrive at a dead end.
So, at any point in the procedure, depending on the type of word you've got in your hands, you may or may not be able to inflect it in some way (there's gonna be a [potentially empty] set of structurally compatible inflections that can be applied to the word). (Then, depending on what the inflection looks like, you may or may not be able to inflect that in some way. And so on and so forth.)
The inflections that you choose to make each step of the way are, obviously, reflective of what you're trying to say (the later elements modify the earlier elements; each new suffix introduced modifies the entire thing on top of which it's placed). The possibilities might feel a little overwhelming at this point, but you'll naturally learn how to create sensible combinations of things as you keep studying grammar (through any old textbook or grammar guide) and seeing examples of conjugation in action (by exposing yourself to the language).

Order, without some rare/obsolete/dialectal suffixes, without onbin (for -ite, -ita…):
VERB_STEM ( [ase~as~sase~sas] [are~rare] | [e]* ) ( u~(u)ru | (i) [ ( te | ta[ru] | tari | tara [ba] | mas ( u[ru] | en | i [ ( te | ta ) ] | yō ) ) ] | e~yo~ro | ō~yō | (a) ( ba | ta i | ta gar u | nu | n | zu | z ar u | na i | naide ) | eba~(u)reba )

[ ] specifies optional elements.

( ) specifies group.

| means logical OR.

~ specifies variants of suffix. Choice of possible variant usually depends on preceding morpheme.

[e]* means Potential suffix -e-, which can be attached only to consonant-stem (godan) verbs. This suffix should not be mistaken with suffix -e- ([得]{う}る): e.g. Positive / Negative forms of kak- (書く) with these suffixes are kak-e-ru (書ける) / kak-e-na-i (書けない) and kak-i-uru (書き得る) / kak-i-e-na-i (書き得ない) respectively.

(u) means that: when attaching given suffix to strong-vowel-stem (ichidan) verbs, suffix-initial /u/ should be elided; when attaching given suffix to weak-vowel-stem (nidan) verbs and irregular verbs se-, ko-, preceding-morpheme-final vowel should be elided. (In Modern Standard Japanese, suffix -e- ([得]{う}る) is maybe the only remaining weak-vowel-stem (nidan) verb: -e- + -(u)ru → -uru.)

(i) means that when attaching given suffix to vowel-stem (ichidan and nidan) verbs, suffix-initial /i/ should be elided.

(a) means that when attaching given suffix to vowel-stem (ichidan and nidan) verbs, suffix-initial /a/ should be elided.

e~yo~ro (Imperative) are etymologically 3 distinct suffixes, but for simplicity, above scheme treats them as variants of 1 suffix. -e used for consonant-stem verbs is speculatively from *-ia ← Continuative -i + *-a. -yo and -ro used for vowel-stem verbs come from exclamative particles. Historically yo became more popular in Western Japanese, while ro became more popular in Eastern Japanese. In Modern Standard Japanese (mostly based on eastern dialect of Tokyo), -yo is more literary.

In case of ase~as~sase~sas (Causative), variants with initial s are used for vowel-stem (ichidan and nidan) verbs.

In case of are~rare (Spontaneous/Passive/Potential/Honorific), variant with initial r is used for vowel-stem (ichidan and nidan) verbs.

-ta-i and -na-i have their own adjectival inflection (e.g. -ta-ku, -ta-kat-ta, -na-ku, -na-kat-ta) skipped here for simplicity.

-ta-gar-u and -z-ar-u have their own inflection (e.g. -ta-gat-ta, -z-ar-i-ki) skipped here for simplicity.

Based on hypothesized etymology, I would actually segment Negative suffixes anu and anai as -an-u and -a-na-i. -an- probably precedes development of 未然形, which emerged from re-interpretation of forms with few suffixes originally starting with a (Negative -an-, Conjectural -am-).

Pseudosuffixes -teru, -teku, -toku, -timau → -tyau etc., which are contractions of -te iru, -te iku, -te oku, -te simau etc., skipped for simplicity.

-ubesi / -ubeki (〜べし・〜べき) ("must, should"), which has either regular Early Middle Japanese adjectival inflection or irregular inflection partially with da, skipped for simplicity.


